# Index out of range for array of objects

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

When refreshing the page I get the error

> fatal error: Index out of range

I can solve the error by deleting the line `posts.removeAll()` but then I get multiple cells of the same type.

and I cannot work anything out of all the other solutions on Stack Overflow for my scenario

I would appreciate any help

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, HomePostCellDelegate {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        collectionView?.register(HomePostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionView?.refreshControl = refreshControl


        fetchAllPosts()
    }

    func handleUpdateFeed() {
        handleRefresh()
    }

    func handleRefresh() {
        print("Handling refresh..")
        posts.removeAll()
        fetchAllPosts()

    }

    fileprivate func fetchAllPosts() {
        fetchPosts()
        fetchFollowingUserIds()
    }

    fileprivate func fetchFollowingUserIds() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        Database.database().reference().child("following").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let userIdsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            userIdsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in
                Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: key, completion: { (user) in
                    self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
                })
            })

        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch following user ids:", err)
        }
    }


    var posts = [Post]()
    fileprivate func fetchPosts() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid) { (user) in
            self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func fetchPostsWithUser(user: User) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user.uid)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

            guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
                guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)
                post.id = key


                    self.posts.append(post)


            })

        }) { (err) in
            print(err)
        }
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 300)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomePostCell

        cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]

        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: You can add the post to posts array if it is not included. You can check the id of the post inside the posts array for not duplicate.

Comment: Does it still break if you call [reloadData()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata) on the collection view at the end of `handleRefresh()`?

Comment: Where is removeAll function body, Could you share ?

Comment: do you fixed the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if posts.count != 0 {
```

cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]
}

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are changing the contents of the `posts` variable without letting the `CollectionView` know that its underlying content has changed.

This means the `CollectionView` for example might still assume that there are 10 posts, while there are 0, because the user just deleted them.

Whenever you change the contents of the `posts` variable, you need to let the `CollectionView` know about it. The easiest way of doing this is using `reloadData()`. This will trigger a reload of the whole view. If you want to be more specific, you can also only update a section (`reloadSection`) or row (`reloadRow`).

[Apple Documentation on reloadData()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata)